I want to show below LW component in acc record page when user navigates from Opportunity list view and hide it when user navigated in any other way?
<template>
    <template if:true={showComponent}>
        <lightning-card title="Opportunities">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={displayedOpportunities}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true"
                    draft-values={draftValues}
                    onsave={handleSave}>
                </lightning-datatable>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template if:true={showViewAllButton}>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick={handleViewAll}>View All</a>
                </template>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
        <lightning-card title="AccountRecordId">
                <p>Get the recordId is <b>{recordId}</b></p>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>    
</template>

JS file
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getOppList from '@salesforce/apex/RelatedOppList.getOppList';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';


const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'Amount', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { label: 'StageName', fieldName: 'StageName', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'CloseDate', fieldName: 'CloseDate', type: 'date', editable: true }
];

export default class LightningtableOpp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    columns = columns;
    @track opportunities = [];
    @track displayedOpportunities = [];
    showViewAllButton = true;
    error;
    @track showComponent = false;
    

    @wire(getOppList, { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredOppList(result) {
        this.wiredOppListResult = result;
        const { error, data } = result;
        if (data) {
            this.opportunities = data;
            this.updateDisplayedOpportunities();
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.opportunities = undefined;
            this.error = error;
        }
    }


    connectedCallback() 
    {                
        const previousPageUrl = window.location.href;       
        console.log('PREVIOUS PAGE URL',previousPageUrl);
        if (previousPageUrl && previousPageUrl.includes('/lightning/o/Opportunity/list')) {            
            this.showComponent = true;
            console.log('Component visibility:', this.showComponent);
        }
        else{
            this.showComponent = false;
            console.log('Component visibility ELSE:', this.showComponent);
        }
    }
    

    updateDisplayedOpportunities() {
        if (this.showViewAllButton) {
            this.displayedOpportunities = this.opportunities.slice(0, 3);
        } 
    }

    handleViewAll() {
        this.showViewAllButton = false;
        this.updateDisplayedOpportunities();
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                apiName: 'OpportunitesFullTable'
            },
        });
    }

    handleSave(event) {
        const recordInputs = event.detail.draftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return { fields };
        });
        console.log('Get the recordInputs are', recordInputs);
        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
            this.showToast('Success', 'Record updated', 'success');
            this.draftValues = [];
            return refreshApex(this.wiredOppListResult);
        }).catch(error => {
            this.showToast('Error', error.body.message, 'error');
        });
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title,
            message,
            variant,
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

When user navigates from opportunities list view  to account record page it works fine showing LWC component.
When again user navigates from Account list view to same Account record page it is not hiding because Account record is already opened in console app from Opportunity list view. Again same account record  tries to open from Account List view, LWC component is not hiding because previously it opened in console app.
How to update the account record page if already account record page is opened from opportunity list view again we navigates to account record page from Account list view?
